# How to show Angular routerLink as plain text in html?

Tags: html, angular6, routerlink

My HTML currently contains a routerLink like below, which works nicely

```html
<a mat-button [routerLink]="['/some','route', hash]">Click Here</a>
```

How can I replace the text "Click Here" with the actual link generated by routerLink? Such that it looks like plain text, like

```html
Your link is: https://localhost:4200/some/route/deadbeef
```

"deadbeef" is the hash value here.

Answer (score 0):

Since the routerLink only generates absolute URLs, like /some/route/deadbeef. I added the following my project:

app.module.ts

Injector for "origin"

```js
{
provide: 'origin',
useValue: window.location.origin
}
```

in my constructor:

```js
@Inject('origin') public origin: string
```

and finally in my HTML code

```html
<a mat-button [routerLink]="['/some','route', hash]">{{origin}}/some/route/{{hash}}</a>
```